# ASP.NET ListView-embedded Web-Control loses state and passed-values on ItemDataBound event handler when page posts back

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, web-controls

This question is about a very strange behavior of web controls. Consider the following please.

### Scenario

I have a web control which is used to show some data. `MyWebControl.ascx` file is the following:

```
<%@ Control ViewStateMode="Enabled" 
            Language="C#" 
            AutoEventWireup="true" 
            CodeFile="MyWebControl.ascx.cs" 
            Inherits="MyWebControl" %>

<div>
   <asp:Label ID="MyLabel1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
   <asp:Label ID="MyLabel2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

And code behind `MyWebControl.ascx.cs` is:

```
public partial class MyWebControl : 
      System.Web.UI.UserControl {
   protected string str1;
   protected string str2;

   public string Str1 {
      get { return this.str1; }
      set { this.str1 = value; }
   }
   public string Str2 {
      get { return this.str2; }
      set { this.str2 = value; }
   }

   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      this.MyLabel1.Text = this.str1;
      this.MyLabel2.Text = this.str2;
   }
}
```

Well, I use this control inside a `ListView` of mine in an ordinary web form. This web form is called `Default.aspx` and, following, I am showing a slice of its code, only the one where the `ListView` resides in:

```
<%@ Page Title="My page" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
         CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="my" TagName="MyWC" Src="~/MyWebControl.ascx" %>
...
...
<div>
   <asp:ListView ID="MyLV_ListView" runat="server" 
                 EnableViewState="true" 
                 OnPreRender="MyLV_ListView_PreRender" 
                 OnItemDataBound="MyLV_ListView_ItemDataBound">
      <ItemTemplate>
         <my:MyWC ID="WC_MyWC" runat="server" />
      </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:ListView>
</div>
```

This web form code-behind `Default.aspx.cs` is:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page {
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      if (!this.IsPostBack) {
         DAO d = new DAO(...); /* This object will contain some data */
                               /* Data are somehow paged, changing index, we have other data */
                               /* Please do not worry about paging, it works, problem is another */
         d.PageIndex = 0;
         this.ViewState["DAO"] = d; /* DAO is serializable */
         this.ViewState["PageIndex"] = 0;
         Data[] data = d.GetData(); /* Returns an array of objects representing my data */
                                    /* Custom way of storing data in objects */
                                    /* GetData use the PageIndex to get only a range of results */
         this.MyLV_ListView.DataSource = data;
         this.MyLV_ListView.DataBind();
      }
   }
   protected void MyLV_ListView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e) {
      if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem) {
         ((MyWebControl)e.Item.FindControl("WC_MyWC")).Str1 = 
            ((Data)e.Item.DataItem).DataField1;
         ((MyWebControl)e.Item.FindControl("WC_MyWC")).Str2 = 
            ((Data)e.Item.DataItem).DataField2;
      }
   }
   protected void MyLV_ListView_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      if (this.IsPostBack)
         this.MyLV_ListView.DataBind();
   }
   // A TreeView will cause the page to reload, 
   // this is the handler called when a tree node is 
   // selected, the node is used to change the page 
   // for showing data in my listview.
   protected void MyLVPaging_TreeView_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      this.ViewState["PageIndex"] = int.Parse(this.MyLVPaging_TreeView.SelectedNode.Value);
      ((DAO)this.ViewState["DAO"]).PageIndex = (int)this.ViewState["PageIndex"];
      // After setting the new index, GetData will return another set of results
      this.MyLV_ListView.DataSource = ((DAO)this.ViewState["DAO"]).GetData();
   }
}
```

### The problem

What is my problem???

Well, when the page loads for the first time I can see some data in the list view, so everything works.

When I select another page, I cause the page to reload and post back... my `ListView` will show the correct number of entries but with no data in it. The web control is placed as many times as the number of retrieved data records, but the web control has no data in it.

### Debugging results

I conducted some debug sessions and this is what happens, please follow me, this is VERY IMPORTANT to understand I guess.

**Page loads for the first time**

1) `Load` page method is executed.

2) `ListView`'s `ItemDataBound` event handler is executed. Well, given that I have three elements in the `Data[]` array in the `DataSource`, the handler is called three times. Inspecting values when proceeding debugging the method, I can see that `((Data)e.Item.DataItem).DataField1` and `((Data)e.Item.DataItem).DataField2` are the correct values retrieved from the bound data source in the `ListView`.
After the method is executed, the debugger cursor moves to `MyWebControl.ascx.cs` to the control's `Page_Load` method. I can see, inspecting variables, that this happens:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   this.MyLabel1.Text = this.str1; // <-- this.str1 has the correct value loaded in the list view itemdatabound event handler.
   this.MyLabel2.Text = this.str2; // <-- this.str2 has the correct value loaded in the list view itemdatabound event handler.
}
```

3) The `ListView` `PreRender` method is called.

4) The page shows and everyting is ok!

**Page posts back after selecting a node in the TreeView**

1) `Load` page method is executed but it does nothing.

2) `MyLVPaging_TreeView_SelectedNodeChanged` is executed. Here I can see that everything has the correct value:

protected void MyLVPaging_TreeView_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   this.ViewState["PageIndex"] = 
      int.Parse(this.MyLVPaging_TreeView.SelectedNode.Value); // <-- The new page
   ((DAO)this.ViewState["DAO"]).PageIndex = 
      (int)this.ViewState["PageIndex"]; // <-- Index saved
   // After setting the new index, GetData will return another set of results
   this.MyLV_ListView.DataSource = 
      ((DAO)this.ViewState["DAO"]).GetData(); // <-- DataSource is changed
}

3) `ListView`'s `ItemDataBound` event handler is executed. Well, here, debugging I can see the same as before, I mean, I can see that new values, new `Data` have been bound to the `ListView`, in fact I can inspect new values that are assigned to the template item.
Obviously, as before, after the method is executed, the debugger cursor moves to `MyWebControl.ascx.cs` to the control's `Page_Load` method.
HERE IS EVIL: I can see the following:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   // Note: inspecting this.IsPostBack I get true!
   this.MyLabel1.Text = this.str1; // <-- this.str1 is null and also this.MyLabel1.Text is null.
   this.MyLabel2.Text = this.str2; // <-- this.str2 is null and also this.MyLabel1.Text is null. view itemdatabound event handler.
}
```

> Well!!! IT LOSES STATE AND ALSO VALUES
>   PASSED BY THE LIST VIEW
>   HANDLER!!!!!!!!!

### My question

What the hell is going on???

### Notes

1) Please, do not focus too much on how I managed data binding on `Load` and `PreRender` events... I have a feeling this is not the error! I guess it is something related to the page lifecycle. However, if you think that this is important detail, let me know.

2) `DAO` and its function `GetData()` are a way to let you understand as quick as possible the scenario which is a little bit more articulated, but with the same exact structure I've shown here.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why don't you move the `this.MyLV_ListView.DataBind()` from `PreRender` to `SelectedNodeChanged`? And why do you need the fields `str1` and `str2` in your UserControl? The  property `Str1` should get/set `this.MyLabel1.Text` and the property `Str2`should get/set `this.MyLabel2.Text`, because the lables' Text are already stored in ViewState.

Comment: @Tim: This is something related to my bad knowledge about Web controls... so these kind of settings are not to be made in the Load???

Comment: what i wanted to say is, you don't need to wait for any event to happen to set the label's text. The properties should directly lead to the corresponding Labels, hence your fields `str1` and `str2` are  redundant. They will be disposed at the end of the Page-Lifecycle as opposed to the Text property of the Labels which are stored in ViewState automatically across postbacks.

Comment: @Tim: OK! Understood, I'll edit my code and see what happens... however thank you, your information was good to know anyway (even if it won't change my problem, let's see). Just two minutes and I'll edit the code to update my results.

Comment: @Tim: Please, post your answer about what you told me... it is correct, the problem was that. This question is yours :) THANLYOU very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my comments:

> Why don't you move the
>   this.MyLV_ListView.DataBind() from
>   PreRender to SelectedNodeChanged? And
>   why do you need the fields str1 and
>   str2 in your UserControl? The property
>   Str1 should get/set this.MyLabel1.Text
>   and the property Str2should get/set
>   this.MyLabel2.Text, because the
>   lables' Text are already stored in
>   ViewState.

Andry:

> ... so these kind of settings are not
>   to be made in the Load?

Me:

> you don't need to wait for any event
>   to happen to set the label's text. The
>   properties should directly lead to the
>   corresponding Labels, hence your
>   fields str1 and str2 are redundant.
>   They will be disposed at the end of
>   the Page-Lifecycle as opposed to the
>   Text property of the Labels which are
>   stored in ViewState automatically
>   across postbacks.